# HTML Header indicates image/jpeg, DevTools indicates document and cache is not working

Tags: http-headers, codeigniter-4

I am trying to cache some images and using the DevTools of MS Edge to analyze the network.
The URL should return only the image via `readfile($image)` and I see the image correctly in the browser.

```
Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 25 May 2020 19:18:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Pragma: no-cache
Debugbar-Time: 1590434336
Debugbar-Link: https://blog.casa.spiti/?debugbar_time=1590434336
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

The `Network` Tab of the Chrome Dev Tools shows `document` for the image.

Questions to this output:

1. What is this expire date of 1981? How do I change it?
2. Is this the reason why the image is not cached?
3. Why is the image being indicated as document? Is it because I use readfile()?

Answer (score 1):

1. Impossible to answer without seeing your server config.
2. Shouldn’t be, `cache-control` is used in preference to `Expires`.
3. If you are loading the image directly in the browser it shows as document - even if it’s an image. That image is the document in that case. If you load the image as part of an HTML document, then it will show as Image in Dev Tools.

Comment: Thanks for the leads, I will look into that.
1. Apache running PHP 7
2. So, withe this output, it should not matter that the Expire header says Cache already expired. The browser should cache it for the next 86400 seconds, right?
3. Thanks a lot for that info, that part drove me insane....

Comment: 1. Something must be setting that to that value. Either in Apache config or PHP. Suggest you track it down to avoid confusion in future. 2. Yes it should not matter. Also make sure you don't have cache disabled (default when dev tools is open). 3. No problem - it can be confusing alright.

Comment: I just went through both config files and did not find anything setting or unsetting the value... But I'll keep looking. Do you have any lead on that? Cache is enabled, that's the first thing I looked into.